# Print session variables in a <div>

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to print session variables that I get from page-1.php into page-2.php into a div. I have managed to get the values via session from page-1 to page-2 but I am not able to print the values into a div(one div) that comes right beneath the menu. When I echo the output, it gets printed on the top-left. Code is mentioned below:

```
 .output{
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo '<div class="output">$_SESSION["val-2"]</div>';    //get session variables
    echo '<div class="output">$_SESSION["val-1"]</div>';
    echo '<div class="output">$_SESSION["val"]</div>';
    ?>

    <div><h1>Page-2</h1></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page-1.php">Page-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page-2.php">Page-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="output"></div>
    </body>
```

[Output I am getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoEDC.png)

Comment: try changing     echo '<div class="output">$_SESSION["val-1"]</div>';
to     echo '<div class="output">'.$_SESSION["val-1"].'</div>';
and see

Comment: @Akintunde Yes sir, I am running XAMPP

Comment: @Satya Thanks, I tried but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate string and variable, it may work,

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<div class="output">'.$_SESSION["val-1"].'</div>';
echo '<div class="output">'.$_SESSION["val-2"].'</div>';
echo '<div class="output">'.$_SESSION["val-3"].'</div>';
?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo '<div class="output">'.$_SESSION["val-1"].$_SESSION["val-2"].$_SESSION["val-3"].'</div>';
?>
```

Hope this one helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it still outputs the result in 3 different div's not a single div and that too at the top-left whereas I want the result to come below the menu.

Comment: When you have written 3 divs, output will also create 3 divs, take care of the position by css

Comment: Thanks, I did it...echo '<div class="output">'.$_SESSION["val-1"].'<br>'.$_SESSION["val-2"].'<br>'.$_SESSION["val"].'</div>';

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `session_start()` before ANYthing, even before the `head` tag or `<!doctype>`.

Change you code to:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!doctype>
<head>
.... 
.output{
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo '<div class="output">';
      echo $_SESSION["val-2"];
      echo $_SESSION["val-1"];
      echo $_SESSION["val"];
    echo "</div>"; 
    ?>
....
```

Comment: I have started the session in body.